# where “your kind” thrive, be free and successful

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "your kind" refer to the kind of people who hate Asians?

> Midnight Rambler tweeted on Mar 30:
> I can imagine the hurt/anger seeing this but...western societies have simultaneously discriminated against asians and created environments **where “your kind” thrive, be free and successful.**
> By all means call out the discrimination, but don’t forget about the rest of the picture.

> [Source](https://twitter.com/MidnightRambl20/status/1376768709352562688)

Comment: This isn't really an English Language question. This tweet is in reply to one where a lady with a Chinese name refers to 'our kind', so it presumably  refers to Asians themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to Asian people living in Europe and America. It is particularly referring to [a tweet](https://twitter.com/RealSexyCyborg/status/1376718415830806528?s=20) by Naomi Wu, in which she says "They [white people] won't help our kind [Asians] ever".

It should be mentioned that this kind of language (speaking of "your kind" etc) is denigrating and inflammatory. It should be avoided if you are not trying to start a fight.